# How to check if an element is visible with WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

With `WebDriver` from Selenium 2.0a2 I am having trouble checking if an element is visible.

`WebDriver.findElement` returns a `WebElement`, which unfortunately doesn't offer an `isVisible` method. I can go around this by using `WebElement.clear` or `WebElement.click` both of which throw an `ElementNotVisibleException`, but this feels very dirty.

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`element instanceof RenderedWebElement` should work.

Comment: Works, but I still find this a bit annoying. I wonder what the reasoning is for not offering an WebElement.isDisplayed.

Comment: This is not working but this interface delegates method isDisplayed and it works. Thanks for the hint. (+1)

Comment: Is this still relevant for selenium 2.0? I don't think there is a need for RenderedWebElement (the class itself is gone).

Comment: @Eugen I think it has been changed to `RemoteWebElement`. But yeah as @sleske wrote `WebElement.isDisplayed` is now available and it probably will work in this use case (I don't have that code available anymore so cannot test).

Comment: Does anyone know the equivalent of this in Python?

Comment: Downvote - no longer the best answer since isDisplayed() was added to web driver. (see sleske's answer)

Comment: For real? The question is about specific version of Selenium (2.0a2). So, using `isDisplayed()` is not a correct answer for the version in question.

Comment: isDisplayed does not work. It says true even when element is clearly not shown.

Answer (score 164):

Even though I'm somewhat late answering the question:

You can now use [`WebElement.isDisplayed()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isDisplayed--) to check if an element is visible.

*Note*:

There are many reasons why an element could be invisible. Selenium tries cover most of them, but there are edge cases where it does not work as expected.

For example, `isDisplayed()` *does* return `false` if an element has `display: none` or `opacity: 0`, but at least in my test, it does not reliably detect if an element is covered by another due to CSS positioning.

Comment: isDisplayed returns true even of element is not visible.

Comment: @SteveStaple: That should not happen. If it does, consider filing a bug.

Comment: I have been informed that it is not a bug, & that this works as expected. displayed does not mean the same to them as it does to the rest of the English speaking world.

Comment: @SteveStaple: Well, welcome to the world of computers. Lots of things don't mean quite the same as they do elsewhere.

Comment: this doesn't say if the element is visible, only if it exists on the page. it could be hidden by other elements and/or be outside the viewport. whether or not the `display` prop is set only covers a fraction of the possible states and will return false positives in a lot of cases.

Comment: @oligofren: Yes, there are many reasons why an element could be invisible - and Selenium does cover most of them. For example, `isDisplayed()` _does_ return `false` if an element is outside the viewport, or has opacity=0. There are certainly edge cases where it does not work as expected, but it does usually work, unless you do very fancy things in your page. Answer updated.

Comment: @sleske isDisplayed() will not work every time. There can be a case that locator also finished when something disappears. so NoSuchElementException error will be generate in that case.

Comment: @RamzanMahmood: Yes, that is by design. You may not invoke `isDisplayed()` on an element that is no longer in the DOM.

Comment: isDisplayed means the element was rendered but it is not necessarily in view or top-level. This means it might be slightly outside the screen or covered by some other element or an overlay / popup.

Answer (score 24):

### Short answer: use `#visibilityOfElementLocated`

None of the answers using `isDisplayed` or similar are correct. They only check if the `display` property is not `none`, not if the element can actually be seen! Selenium had a bunch of static utility methods added in the [`ExpectedConditions`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) class. Two of them can be used in this case:

- [visibilityOfElementLocated](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) (element is allowed not to exist)
- [visibilityOf](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOf-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-) (element must exist)

**Usage**

```
@Test
// visibilityOfElementLocated has been statically imported
public demo(){
    By searchButtonSelector = By.className("search_button");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    driver.get(homeUrl);

    WebElement searchButton = wait.until(                
            visibilityOfElementLocated
            (searchButtonSelector)); 

    //clicks the search button 
    searchButton.click();
```

### Custom visibility check running on the client

This was my answer before finding out about the utility methods on `ExpectedConditions`. It might still be relevant, as I assume it does more than the method mentioned above, which only checks the element has a height and a width.

In essence: this cannot be answered by Java and the `findElementBy*` methods and `WebElement#isDisplayed` alone, as they can only tell you if an element *exists*, not if it is actually *visible*. The OP hasn't defined what *visible* means, but it normally entails

- it has an `opacity` > 0
- it has the `display` property set to something else than `none`
- the `visibility` prop is set to `visible`
- there are no other elements hiding it (it's the topmost element)

Most people would also include the requirement that it is actually within the viewport as well (so a person would be able to see it).

For some reason, this quite normal need is not met by the pure Java API, while front-ends to Selenium that builds upon it often implements some variation of `isVisible`, which is why I knew this should be possible. And after browsing the source of the Node framework *WebDriver.IO* I found [the source](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/blob/v5.0.0-beta.2/packages/webdriverio/src/commands/element/isDisplayedInViewport.js) of `isVisible`, which is now renamed to the more aptly name of `isVisibleInViewport` in the 5.0-beta.

Basically, they implement the custom command as a call that *delegates to a javascript that runs on the client* and does the actual work! This is the "server" bit:

```
export default function isDisplayedInViewport () {
    return getBrowserObject(this).execute(isDisplayedInViewportScript, {
        [ELEMENT_KEY]: this.elementId, // w3c compatible
        ELEMENT: this.elementId // jsonwp compatible
    })
}
```

So the interesting bit is the javascript sent to run on the client:

```
/**
 * check if element is visible and within the viewport
 * @param  {HTMLElement} elem  element to check
 * @return {Boolean}           true if element is within viewport
 */
export default function isDisplayedInViewport (elem) {
    const dde = document.documentElement

    let isWithinViewport = true
    while (elem.parentNode && elem.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect) {
        const elemDimension = elem.getBoundingClientRect()
        const elemComputedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(elem)
        const viewportDimension = {
            width: dde.clientWidth,
            height: dde.clientHeight
        }

        isWithinViewport = isWithinViewport &&
                           (elemComputedStyle.display !== 'none' &&
                            elemComputedStyle.visibility === 'visible' &&
                            parseFloat(elemComputedStyle.opacity, 10) > 0 &&
                            elemDimension.bottom > 0 &&
                            elemDimension.right > 0 &&
                            elemDimension.top < viewportDimension.height &&
                            elemDimension.left < viewportDimension.width)

        elem = elem.parentNode
    }

    return isWithinViewport
}
```

This piece of JS can actually be copied (almost) verbatim into your own codebase (remove `export default` and replace `const` with `var` in case of non-evergreen browsers)! To use it, read it from `File` into a `String` that can be sent by Selenium for running on the client.

Another interesting and related script that might be worth looking into is [selectByVisibleText](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/blob/master/packages/webdriverio/src/commands/element/selectByVisibleText.js).

If you haven't executed JS using Selenium before you could have [a small peek into this](https://www.guru99.com/execute-javascript-selenium-webdriver.html) or browse the [JavaScriptExecutor API](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html).

Usually, try to always use non-blocking async scripts (meaning [#executeAsyncScript](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html)), but since we already have a synchronous, blocking script we might as well use the normal sync call.  The returned object can be many types of Object, so cast approprately. This could be one way of doing it:

```
/** 
 * Demo of a java version of webdriverio's isDisplayedInViewport
 * https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/blob/v5.0.0-beta.2/packages/webdriverio/src/commands/element/isDisplayedInViewport.js
 * The super class GuiTest just deals with setup of the driver and such
 */
class VisibleDemoTest extends GuiTest {
    public static String readScript(String name) {
        try {
            File f = new File("selenium-scripts/" + name + ".js");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( file ) );
            return reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
        } catch(IOError e){
            throw new RuntimeError("No such Selenium script: " + f.getAbsolutePath()); 
        }
    }

    public static Boolean isVisibleInViewport(RemoteElement e){
        // according to the Webdriver spec a string that identifies an element
        // should be deserialized into the corresponding web element,
        // meaning the 'isDisplayedInViewport' function should receive the element, 
        // not just the string we passed to it originally - how this is done is not our concern
        //
        // This is probably when ELEMENT and ELEMENT_KEY refers to in the wd.io implementation
        //
        // Ref https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-json-deserialize
        return js.executeScript(readScript("isDisplayedInViewport"), e.getId());
    }

    public static Boolean isVisibleInViewport(String xPath){
        driver().findElementByXPath("//button[@id='should_be_visible']");
    }

    @Test
    public demo_isVisibleInViewport(){
        // you can build all kinds of abstractions on top of the base method
        // to make it more Selenium-ish using retries with timeouts, etc
        assertTrue(isVisibleInViewport("//button[@id='should_be_visible']"));
        assertFalse(isVisibleInViewport("//button[@id='should_be_hidden']"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

I have the following 2 suggested ways:

1. You can use `isDisplayed()` as below:

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.id("idOfElement")).isDisplayed();
   ```
2. You can define a method as shown below and call it:

   ```
   public boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
     try {
       driver.findElement(by);
       return true;
     }
   catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) {
       return false;
     }
   }
   ```

Now, you can do assertion as below to check either the element is present or not:

```
assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.id("idOfElement")));
```

Comment: but this will always wait until timeout occurs

Comment: @Anna: It's my pleasure - Thank you.

Comment: this doesn't say if the element is visible, only if it exists on the page. it could be hidden by other elements and/or be outside the viewport, hence give false positives.

Comment: you can set the fail message within same line, that is a plus 
Assert.assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.id("idOfElement")), "LogOut Button is not visible.");

Answer (score 9):

If you're using C#, it would be driver.Displayed. Here's an example from my own project:

```
if (!driver.FindElement(By.Name("newtagfield")).Displayed)      //if the tag options is not displayed
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("expand-folder-tags")).Click();    //make sure the folder and tags options are visible
```

Comment: Visible is not the same as displayed. That just checks if the element has the css prop `display` set to something else than `none`. It still might be hidden by other elements, have a zero height, etc. This won't catch that.

Answer (score 3):

It is important to see if the element is visible or not as the `Driver.FindElement` will only check the HTML source. But popup code could be in the page html, and not be visible. Therefore, `Driver.FindElement` function returns a false positive (and your test will fail)

Comment: If the element is present in HTML code then findElement will pass even if the element is hidden. Or say not visible (like a dropdown menu). The question is to find whether element is visible or not.

Comment: @CallumRogers Check my answer. It presents a Java version of how the Selenium based Webdriver.io NodeJS framework does it. Basically you need to run JS on the client to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

Verifying ele is visible.

```
public static boolean isElementVisible(final By by)
    throws InterruptedException {
        boolean value = false;

        if (driver.findElements(by).size() > 0) {
            value = true;
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: Not related to the OP, but you can simplify your function. How about:

return driver.findElements(by).size() > 0;

Comment: that just checks if you can find it, not if it is visible. it will find a hidden element.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using page factory then you can try the below code for your reference:

```
public static boolean isElementVisible(WebElement webElement, int timeOut) {
    try {
      WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOut);
      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(webElement));
      return true;
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer from [oligofren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/200987/oligofren) - the method isDisplayedInViewport works. Thanks for that. Helped me. Just have a couple of suggestions -

1. It is fine to check for opacity, visibility and display for all the parent nodes for the element in question as these when set on parent can hide the element as well, however the dimensions can be checked for the element itself only. In my case, the topmost parent node of the element scrolled out of the viewport and the dimension check was not allowing the method to return true.
2. For ensuring that the complete element comes to view instead of just the top of it, we can use height and width instead of x and y (top/left)

I have used the following code based on what [oligofren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/200987/oligofren) provided in his answer. I am passing the WebElement as an argument to the selenium execute_script method and reading it as elem

```
    var elem = arguments[0]
    const dde = document.documentElement
    let isWithinViewport = true
    var firstTime = true
    while (elem.parentNode && elem.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect) {
        const elemDimension = elem.getBoundingClientRect()
        const elemComputedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(elem)
        const viewportDimension = {
            width: dde.clientWidth,
            height: dde.clientHeight
        }
        let dimCondition = true
        if (firstTime){

        dimCondition = dimCondition && (elemDimension.bottom > 0 &&
                            elemDimension.right > 0 &&
                            (elemDimension.top + elemDimension.height) < viewportDimension.height  &&
                            (elemDimension.left + elemDimension.width) < viewportDimension.width)
        firstTime = false

        }
        isWithinViewport = isWithinViewport && dimCondition &&
                           (elemComputedStyle.display !== 'none' &&
                            elemComputedStyle.visibility === 'visible' &&
                            parseFloat(elemComputedStyle.opacity, 10) > 0
                             )
        console.log(isWithinViewport)
        console.log(elem.nodeName)

        elem = elem.parentNode
    }
    return isWithinViewport
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isElementFound( String text) {
        try{
            WebElement webElement = appiumDriver.findElement(By.xpath(text));
            System.out.println("isElementFound : true :"+text + "true");
        }catch(NoSuchElementException e){
            System.out.println("isElementFound : false :"+text);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    text is the xpath which you would be passing when calling the function.
the return value will be true if the element is present else false if element is not pressent
```

Comment: Please provide some more details to your answer. How does this work and how does this solve the problem of the OP?

Comment: It's not about checking if an element is present, but whether it is _visible_.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I would do it (please ignore worry Logger class calls):

```
public boolean isElementExist(By by) {
    int count = driver.findElements(by).size();
    if (count>=1) {
        Logger.LogMessage("isElementExist: " + by + " | Count: " + count, Priority.Medium);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        Logger.LogMessage("isElementExist: " + by + " | Could not find element", Priority.High);
        return false;
    }   
}

public boolean isElementNotExist(By by) {
    int count = driver.findElements(by).size();
    if (count==0) {
        Logger.LogMessage("ElementDoesNotExist: " + by, Priority.Medium);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        Logger.LogMessage("ElementDoesExist: " + by, Priority.High);
        return false;
    }   
}

public boolean isElementVisible(By by) {
    try {
        if (driver.findElement(by).isDisplayed()) {
            Logger.LogMessage("Element is Displayed: " + by, Priority.Medium);
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {       
        Logger.LogMessage("Element is Not Displayed: " + by, Priority.High);
        return false;
    }       

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I am doing the same. Using isDisplayed() directly will throw exception, so can be a check but can't be a condition to drive the workflow like this.

Answer (score -1):

```
    try{
        if( driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div***")).isDisplayed()){
          System.out.println("Element is Visible");
        }
}
catch(NoSuchElementException e){
   else{
     System.out.println("Element is InVisible");
        }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: this doesn't say if the element is visible, only if it exists on the page. it could be hidden by other elements and/or be outside the viewport.

Answer (score -3):

try this

```
public boolean isPrebuiltTestButtonVisible() {
    try {

        if (preBuiltTestButton.isEnabled()) {

            return true;

        } else {

            return false;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```