# With cucumber selenium webdriver java, how to check presenceOfElement for a WebElement

Tags: selenium

I'm writing an automatic test.
I'm doing that thanks to this guide :
[sukesh15.gitbooks.io](https://sukesh15.gitbooks.io/cucumber-jvm-test-framework)

Here is an extract of my Page class :

```
public class TestCuCumBerPage {

WebDriver driver;

@FindBy(id = "display")
private WebElement buttonDisplay;

public void buttonDisplayClick() throws Throwable {
    WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30))           
      .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("display")));

    buttonDisplay.click();  
}
}
```

I've to use the id "display" :

- in the @FindBy declaration (give the WebElement "buttonDisplay")
- in the WebDriverWait

To avoid that, I've created a constant **BUTTON_DISPLAY_ID** with the Id :

```
public class TestCuCumBerPage {

WebDriver driver;

private final String BUTTON_DISPLAY_ID = "display";
@FindBy(id = BUTTON_DISPLAY_ID)
private WebElement buttonDisplay;

public void buttonDisplayClick() throws Throwable {
    WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30))           
      .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id(BUTTON_DISPLAY_ID)));

    buttonDisplay.click();  
}
}
```

Is there a better way, for example something like this
        WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30))
          .until(ExpectedConditions.**presenceOfWebElement**(buttonDisplay));

( I found a greet explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533597/webdriver-how-to-check-if-an-page-object-web-element-exists))

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isElementPresent(WebElement element){
  try{

     WebElement;

     return true;

}
catch(Excception e){

System.out.println("Element not present!!");
return false;

}
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation.  Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers.  Your answer is in the moderation queue for being low-quality.