# Get visible text of page

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How do I get the visible text portion of a web page with selenium webdriver without the HTML tags?

I need something equivalent to the function HtmlPage.asText() from Htmlunit.

It is not enough to take the text with the function WebDriver.getSource and parse it with jsoup because there could be in the page hidden elements (by external CSS) which I am not interested in them.

Comment: If you use firefox you can take a screenshot.  If you need to actually have the text are you sure you need everything that is visible?  Normally when I have to scrape something I only care about a few elements on the page.  Also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646195/how-to-check-if-an-element-is-visible-with-webdriver

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Doing `By.tagName("body")` (or some other selector to select the top element), then performing `getText()` on that element will return all of the visible text.

Comment: What kind of object is "By"?

Comment: @macdonjo It's the way that Selenium separates their selectors.  `driver.findElement(By.selectorType("selector"))` http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html

Comment: Oh, I figured it out. I'm Python and that's the Java syntax. Thanks!

Comment: In python, the getText() method does not exists. Instead, we should use element.text

Answer (score 13):

I can help you with C# Selenium.

By using this you can select all the text on that particular page and save it to a text file at your preferred location.

Make sure you are using this stuff:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
```

After reaching the particular page try using this code.

```
IWebElement body = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));
var result = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body")).Text;

// Folder location
var dir = @"C:Textfile" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();

// If the folder doesn't exist, create it
if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);

// Creates a file copiedtext.txt with all the contents on the page.
File.AppendAllText(Path.Combine(dir, "Copiedtext.txt"), result);
```

Comment: Man, people are mean.  Why was this downvoted?  Cause the person that answered added a lil' extra code to save what was captured to a textfile?  It has all the same code as the ones that answered above.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure what language you're using, but in C# the IWebElement object has a .Text method. That method shows all text that is displayed between the element's opening and closing tag.

I would create an IWebElement using XPath to grab the entire page. In other words, you're grabbing the body element and looking at the text in it.

```
string pageText = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//html/body/")).Text;
```

If the above code does not work for selenium, use this:

```
string yourtext= driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText();
```

Comment: I solved it with the command driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText()

Comment: perfect.  That looks to be the java equivalent to the C# code above.  The key is to grab the body not html tag for efficiency.  I tend to use XPath because of how easy it is to get xpath in Chrome but you can use By.cssSelector("body") or the By.tagName("body") as you used.  They all select the same element.

Comment: "//html/body/" - this xpath is not valid due extra "/" at the end. 
Correct code is:
string pageText = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//html/body")).Text;