# How do you assert a text in your page body in webdriver c#?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, assert

I need to assert if page body contains text "error", how would I do that? I got to this point and I am getting error on .getText

```
driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body")).getText().Equals("Error")
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?
Please remember that stackoverflow is not a website where you'd turn to get code written for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18338377/43846

Comment: driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body")).getText().Equals("Error")

and gettext is marked as error saying "IWebElement does not contain a definition..."

Comment: Ah, that's the Java version. For C#, use [`.Text`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_Text.htm). Also, you should be checking if the text _Contains_ "error", rather than Equals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really want to do it this way... but since you asked, here is the answer.

```
driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body")).Text.Contains("Error");
```

You were using `.getText()` which is Java. You were also using `.Equals()` but what you meant was `.Contains()` because the entirety of the body tag is likely not to be only "Error".

What I would recommend is for you to narrow down to the element that actually contains the "Error" text and then use the line above (with the proper locator), e.g.

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("the ID of the element that contains Error")).Text.Contains("Error");
```

You'd have to provide the surrounding HTML for the element for us to help you any more specifically.