# How can I find visible only elements on a page with Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I got a page with couple hidden spans with same class. I need to check, if is one of them displayed on a page. I tried to use `@driver.find_element(:class, 'some class').displayed?` but it returns `false`, when visible span not first with that class on DOM. Is any way I can handle that?

UPDATE

HTML

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <div class="span1" style="display: none;">
        <span class="some class">Some Error</span>
      </div>
      <div class="span2" style="display: none;">
        <span class="some class">Some Error</span>
      </div>
      <div class="span3" style>
        <span class="some class">Some Error</span>
      </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML and your code trials

Answer (score 1):

Instead of use `style="display: none"` you can use a CSS class for not display elements like:

```
.hidden { 
   display: none;
}
```

Now you can check if the element have this class.

UPDATE

If you can't change the HTML, may you can use the function `element.isDisplayed()`, does returns false if element have `display: none` or `opacity: 0`, i found it in another question: [How to check if an element is visible with WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646195/how-to-check-if-an-element-is-visible-with-webdriver)

Comment: I can't change HTML.

Comment: You can use the function `element.isDisplayed()`, does returns false if element have `display: none` or opacity: 0`, i found it in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646195/how-to-check-if-an-element-is-visible-with-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

To check if any of the element is **displayed** on a page even when the visible `<span>` is not first within the parent node as per the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) you have provided, you can use the following solution:

- Using *XPath*:

  ```
  @driver.find_element(:xpath,"//span[@class='some class']").displayed?
  ```