# How to check if an item is displayed or even there in selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have a website that has anywhere from 3 to 4 images on it. If it tries to acquire the 4th image and it's not there the program blows up. I want to check if the fourth is there, and if it is I want to acquire it, if not I want to go on with the program. I want to do it without using try and except. I've tried .isDisplayed could not get it to work.

This is the driver statement that acquires the image.
Image3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="goods_thumb_content"]/ul/li[3]').get_attribute("data-bigimg");

I'm using Selenium and here is the code:

```
      #This is the code when all four images are present. and when it's not the last <li> <l/> is not 
      present.

     <ul>
     <li class="thumb_item active logsss_event_cl" data-isself="1" data- 
     bigimg="https://gloimg.rglcdn.com/rosegal/pdm-product-pic/Clothing/2021/03/09/source- 
     img/20210309165545_60473811b6a7c.jpg" data-zoomimg="https://gloimg.rglcdn.com/rosegal/pdm- 
     product-pic/Clothing/2021/03/09/source-img/20210309165545_60473811b6a7c.jpg" data-logsss-const- 
     value="{'x': 'change_pic'}" style="height: 131.6px;">  <img 
     src="https://gloimg.rglcdn.com/rosegal/pdm-product-pic/Clothing/2021/03/09/grid- 
     img/1618874299184494137.jpg?im_scale=w75_1x" alt="Plus Size Paisley Print Empire Waist 
     Asymmetric Tank Top -  "> </li>

     <li class="thumb_item logsss_event_cl" data-isself="1" data- 
     bigimg="https://gloimg.rglcdn.com/rosegal/pdm-product-pic/Clothing/2021/03/09/source- 
     img/20210309165545_60473811c9ce8.jpg" data-zoomimg="https://gloimg.rglcdn.com/rosegal/pdm- 
     product-pic/Clothing/2021/03/09/source-img/20210309165545_60473811c9ce8.jpg" data-logsss-const- 
     value="{'x': 'change_pic'}" style="height: 131.6px;">  <img 
     src="https://gloimg.rglcdn.com/rosegal/pdm-product-pic/Clothing/2021/03/09thumb- 
     img/1615251725078779977.jpg?im_scale=w75_1x" alt="Plus Size Paisley Print Empire Waist 
     Asymmetric Tank Top -  "> </li>

     <li class="thumb_item logsss_event_cl" data-isself="1" data- 
     bigimg="https://gloimg.rglcdn.com/rosegal/pdm-product-pic/Clothing/2021/03/09/source- 
     img/20210309165545_60473811df353.jpg" data-zoomimg="https://gloimg.rglcdn.com/rosegal/pdm- 
     product-pic/Clothing/2021/03/09/source-img/20210309165545_60473811df353.jpg" data-logsss-const- 
     value="{'x': 'change_pic'}" style="height: 131.6px;">  <img 
     src="https://gloimg.rglcdn.com/rosegal/pdm-product-pic/Clothing/2021/03/09thumb- 
     img/1615251725121900529.jpg?im_scale=w75_1x" alt="Plus Size Paisley Print Empire Waist 
     Asymmetric Tank Top -  "> </li>           

     #The <li> below is not present when the fourth image is not there.

    <li class="thumb_item logsss_event_cl" data-isself="1" data- 
    bigimg="https://gloimg.rglcdn.com/rosegal/pdm-product-pic/Clothing/2021/03/09/source- 
    img/20210309165545_60473811f1542.jpg" data-zoomimg="https://gloimg.rglcdn.com/rosegal/pdm- 
    product-pic/Clothing/2021/03/09/source-img/20210309165545_60473811f1542.jpg" data-logsss-const- 
    value="{'x': 'change_pic'}" style="height: 131.6px;">  <img 
    src="https://gloimg.rglcdn.com/rosegal/pdm-product-pic/Clothing/2021/03/09thumb- 
    img/1615251725802705831.jpg?im_scale=w75_1x" alt="Plus Size Paisley Print Empire Waist Asymmetric 
    Tank Top -  "> </li> 
    </ul>
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/2646195/13552470

Comment: 'If it tries to acquire the 4th image and it's not there the program blows up.'  -- what does "blows up" mean? Do you get an exception?

Comment: How would I find the len of the ul or the number of li's in the code. Then I could just do a for in range.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of identifying each element individually like this

```
Image3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="goods_thumb_content"]/ul/li[3]').get_attribute("data-bigimg")
```

Make use of `find_elements`, maybe something like this:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="goods_thumb_content"]/ul/li')
images = []
for element in elements:
    images.append(element.get_attribute("data-bigimg"))
```

This will give you an array with however many elements there are matching `'//*[@id="goods_thumb_content"]/ul/li'`
To define your `Image1`, `Image2`, etc. you can get them from `images`

```
Image1 = images[0]
Image2 = images[1]
....
```

Comment: It get and error:    File "C:\Users\daver\Dev\rosegal\rosegal\this.py", line 112
    images.append(element.get_attribute("data-bigimg"))")   
                                                            ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: You have a typo, there is an extra `")` at the end of your line: `("data-bigimg"))")` should be `("data-bigimg"))`

Comment: Is this the array '//*[@id="goods_thumb_content"]/ul/li'    jhow do I  Make Image1 =   and Image2 = . . .

Comment: If that's what you really want just define `Image1 = images[0]`, see updated answer

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me but Now I'm get  Image4 = images[4]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: It should be `Image4 = images[3]`