# Element visibility check in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
List<WebElement> btnlogoutprofilelist = PageFactory.getInstance().getU4FLoginPage().getBtnlogoutprofilelist();
System.out.println(btnlogoutprofilelist.size());
```

Above method I am using to check element visibility. but it is taking more time to get list of element. nearly it is one min to get List of element.

I tried `isDisplayed()` but that element not present in the DOM due to that it is returning `nosuchelement` exception. `isDisplayed` method not returning boolean value. Please guide me to check element visibility in Selenium Java

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if an element is visible with WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646195/how-to-check-if-an-element-is-visible-with-webdriver)

Comment: Yes, i got the information, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I see from your question, you actually want to validate element presence, not visibility.
To do so the simplest way is to use something like `driver.findElements(By.xpath(the_xpath_locator)).isEmpty();`
In case element no present on the page the list will be empty.
Otherwise non-empty.