# isDisplayed in selenium returning false all the time even element is there

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

```
driver.findElements(By.id("1234")).size() == 1 returns true
driver.findElement(By.id("1234"))).isDisplayed() returns false
```

When I paste selector I can clearly see it in html and in browser, it is not hidden.

Does anyone know solution with JS. Executor in combination with selenium?

Comment: Can you provide the HTML?

Comment: Sorry, I cant do that.

Comment: May be you are not providing sufficient time. Have you tried explicit wait?

Comment: I can see it in debug mode it is not with wait. I see now that there are lot of issues with isDisplayed(). But trying to find other solution like maybe         return js.executeScript(readScript("isDisplayedInViewport"), e.getId());

Comment: If it working in debug mode means you need to add wait.

Comment: It is not working in any mode, but it is also not related with the waiting. Something similar , but not same is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646195/how-to-check-if-an-element-is-visible-with-webdriver